# Angular Universal direct url navigation with iisnode

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service, angular-universal

I have a angular universal application. When running locally (using express) everything works fine. It also works when running inside of node. However when I deploy production build to IIS with iisnode direct url navigate returns 500 Internal Server Error. I've had no luck with running it in node on azure.

Comment: Check the logs inside iis

Comment: Can you upload your sample code (be careful to hide confidential information)? This will help you solve your two problems.

Comment: I created a new angular application, added universal per the docs. I created a new route i.e.: /contact-us. contact us loads fine, If I hit refresh I get 500 internal server error.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66871045/pm2-not-found-on-azure-app-service-with-node-14-runtime/66880978#66880978

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you use the contents of the `build` folder generated after `npm run build` when you publish.  Like pic [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66871045/pm2-not-found-on-azure-app-service-with-node-14-runtime/66880978#66880978). It's a good solution, and it works for me.

[image: soultion]

**Copy blow file to wwwroot folder.**

[image]

[image]

## [Reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66764991/my-azure-web-application-on-linux-is-not-working-the-error-message-on-azure-log/66812267#66812267)

[image]