# My Azure Web Application on Linux is not working. The error message on azure logs "react-scripts: not found" and github "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE ”

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm having a problem with the Azure Web Application. The problem is this ... After creating a Web Service that uses a Linux service plan to upload my front-end app that was developed in React.js, the following error started to appear after a day of testing ... when i click on my website link it loads for about 5 minutes (this time can vary up to 15 minutes), and an error appears - :( Application Error , together with a link for Azure Diagnostics. This link takes me to a screen where it shows me some errors and a table with errors 503 and 502.3, I'll put the image here in the post, I just don't know what to do, I started using azure a short time ago and this is my first contact with this type of error.

[discussion about the bug in the microsoft community](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/289172/my-web-application-is-down.html)

The link above shows a discussion that I opened in the microsoft community where I followed the tips, however, the error persisted.

In one of my last attempts I cleared my code cache in Visual Studio Code and deleted the node modules, after that I executed the command "yarn install" and when I tried to perform the deployment I received a different error with the name "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE".

As was requested in one of the comments I created a repository and made the code I am trying to deploy for testing available ... follow the link github.com/LucasClaraCloud/project_Frontend-

Comment: Please update the error information log of `503` and `502.3` and `npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE`errors in the post.

Comment: The fastest solution is to recreate a sample code that does not contain any examples of confidential information. We can help you quickly locate the wrong information and solve the problem.

Comment: @JasonPan As was requested in one of the comments I created a repository and made the code I am trying to deploy for testing available ... follow the link https://github.com/LucasClaraCloud/project_Frontend-

Comment: After testing, it is impossible to use github for continuous deployment in the simplest way. The answer I gave has a better choice, at least when redeploying, it takes the least time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your project is too complicated. After testing, I can only provide you with an idea. It works for me**

> 1. Deploy the build folder generated after `npm run build` to the `/home/site/wwwroot` folder path.

> 2. Then add startup command on portal with `npx serve -s`.**

---

## Why

Under normal circumstances, deployment is the folder after deploying the build. The advantages are as follows,

**1. Security**

This can protect the security of the file code. Generally, few developers will directly deploy source code files to a web server.

**2. Fast**

The compiled files are relatively small and the deployment is very fast.

---

**Test steps and phenomena::**

1. Use github for continuous deployment. In the git action, the release is successful, but the web page prompts the same as you described, Application Error. View the log the same as yours.
2. Try to FTP the project file to wwwroot (no node_modules folder), and then execute npm install. It runs for a long time, and finally an error occurs.

## Test Result

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great day, sorry for the delay to appear here, I'm trying to replicate the steps you described, but, I can't find this folder / home / site / wwwroot. Could you explain in more detail how I do this part? When I look for this folder it gives me the following error "No such file or directory"

Comment: @LucasdeLagosPandolfiGarcia You need to open scm site.

Comment: Thank you @JasonPan, the application is running again, your answer was correct!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, when you said that my project was too complicated, you were referring to what exactly? I'm still new to programming and I'm looking for tips to improve my work. Would you have any suggestions to improve the project?

Comment: @LucasdeLagosPandolfiGarcia My description is not appropriate. What I said is complicated because this is not an entry-level sample project. There will be many complicated problems when the source file is deployed on IIS, but the folder after compilation only needs to have a webserver, so Will reduce a lot of configuration on iis. Usually our developers are the folders after the build is released.

Comment: I have another problem with deployment, I opened another post in the community, follow the link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67075651/azure-web-application-deployment-successful-but-does-not-update-the-web-applica)