# Azure Web application deployment successful, but does not update the web application

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

Previously I was having an error with the deployment of my React application on Web Service Linux on Azure. This problem was solved in the previous post I did, follow the link:
[My Azure Web Application on Linux is not working. The error message on azure logs "react-scripts: not found" and github "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE ”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66764991/my-azure-web-application-on-linux-is-not-working-the-error-message-on-azure-log/66812267?noredirect=1#comment118363596_66812267).

Now I am having another problem which consists of the following:
After deploying to the Azure platform (I'm using the github option for deployment) and receiving a  [successful deployment notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pdr0.png), upon entering my github repository, I received the error
"npm ERR! Code ELIFECYCLE" (follow the link to view the entire log: https://mega.nz/folder/eth0WSiL#pGvXl2yShQfUrNELCKD3cA). Upon entering the application and testing it I noticed that the deployment really did not work.

An important point worth mentioning that in the previous problem the solution passed by @JasonPan worked, but when we tested it I still used the Azure classic
deployment center, which was removed a few days ago and after trying to use the current deployment center I came across this error.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve the problem. I needed to do two things within my .yml file, they were:
add a CI: false and remove the npm run test
Here is the code:

```
    jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Node.js version
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: '14.x'

    - name: npm install, build
      run: |
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present

    - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: node-app
        path: .

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      CI: false
      name: 'production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
```

The .yml file before it was changed:

```
jobs:
      build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
        steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
        - name: Set up Node.js version
          uses: actions/setup-node@v1
          with:
            node-version: '14.x'
    
        - name: npm install, build, and test
          run: |
            npm install
            npm run build --if-present
            npm run test --if-present

    
        - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
          uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
          with:
            name: node-app
            path: .
    
      deploy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        needs: build
        environment:
          name: 'production'
          url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
```