# pm2 not found on Azure App service with Node 14 runtime

Tags: angular, linux, azure, azure-web-app-service, pm2

What I am trying to achieve is to deploy Angular 9 app to Azure App service with Linux OS (Windows does not suit me because Linux is cheaper)
I created Linux web app with Node 14 runtime.
After I deployed my app I see Azure default web page. I tried to resolve that as it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59707804/deployed-angular-app-to-azure-web-app-but-showing-the-default-azure-page)

Steps I did on Linux web app with Node 14 runtime:

1. I added this

   pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa

to AppService->Configuration->General Settings->Startup Command

2. Saved configuration and restarted App Service But got pm2 not found error.
3. Connected to web app using ssh and have run

   npm install pm2 -g
4. Restarted App Service but still getting pm2 not found.

The question is how to host Angular 9 on Linux app service with Node 14? Should I fix that pm2 not found or I can use some other approach (but still with Linux OS) to solve that?

Comment: Changing your stack to node 12LTS will solve your problem, using 14 LTS is currently not feasible.

Comment: @JasonPan proposal to use "npx serve -s" with Node 14 LTS worked fine for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Newest

If you are not concerned about the release method, it is recommended that you execute ng build locally, and then drag and drop all the files in the `<your project name>` folder directly to wwwroot, or use FTP to upload. Then modify startup cmd with `npx serve -s`, it also can work.

[image]

**Files in local.**

[image]

**Files in wwwroot on azure.**

[image]

## Previous

After testing, I think this should be a bug. If you must use node 14LTS, I suggest you raise a support ticket on portal for help.

**Recurring problem:**

1. Create a linux node 14LTS web app.
2. Create ng9 project, use vscode deploy and success. Open website and show us default page.
3. Add startup cmd with `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa` or `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/dist/<your project name> --no-daemon --spa` , and all failed.

**Try to solve:**

4. I change `Major version` in `Stack settings`, and the project runs normally.

[image]

Comment: "npx serve -s" solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Solved the problem. Many Thanks.

Comment: No drag and drop was needed. Just using `npx serve -s` in Startup command was enough to fix it for me.

Comment: Dear, in my case I wrote: node dist/server/main.js (in my case was an ng universal app)
Can help me to figure out, why ?