# Trying to deploy Vue App to Azure App Service, results in Error: Cannot find module '../package.json'

Tags: node.js, azure, vue.js, yaml, github-actions

I've got a simple Vue SPA that builds and can be served without problem locally, but when I try and build and deploy via GitHub Actions to an Azure App Service, it just results in the '**:( Application Error**' page when launching.

Below is the pretty much default workflow `.yml`, the app service configuration, and the error log from trying to build the app.

I assume the files are built from the `/dist` folder at `/home/site/wwwroot`, where node_modules are installed and package.json is generated.. but it doesn't seem like it is (there are no files when checking wwwroot, so build failed?)

Any help would be appreciated, I've been stuck on this for a whole day and will happily provide more info. I've also deployed the NodeJS backend to an app service without too much hassle, so I'm familiar with the process -- just can't get this frontend up!

```
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - shelf-library

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '16.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: dist/

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'shelf-library'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_11D7C84BF0CE47B68181C49B9ED47D19 }}
          package: .
```

[image]

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

Check the below steps to create  `VueJS` and deploy to Azure App Service using Git Hub Actions.

Thanks @Anthony Salemo for the clear steps.

In Command prompt, run the below command to create a Vue App.

```cs
vue create  myvueapp
```

[image]

Navigate to the root directory of the application `cd myvueapp` and run

```cs
yarn serve
```

[image]

***or***

```
npm run serve
```

[image]

- Run `npm run build` command for production build.`dist` folder will be created.
- Push the application to GitHub Repository.
  You can check the code available in my [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/HarshithaVeeramalla/myvuesample).

***My GitHub folder structure***

[image]

- Create an Azure App service

[image]

- Navigate to your `App Service` =>`Deployment Center` and select the code repo from your GitHub.

[image]

- Initially I got the below content page when I tried to access the App.

[image]

- Add the `Startup Command` in `Configuration` => `General Settings`.

```cs
 pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/dist --spa --no-daemon
```

- Initially even I got the same Application Error.

[image]

- In Git Hub I can see the build and deploy action is not yet completed.

[image]

- Wait for the build to deploy successfully.

[image]

***My deployed folder structure in KUDU Console***

[image]

- Now Iam able to access the Application without any issues.

[image]

Comment: I've followed near the exact same steps for deployment, the only difference I see is that my .yml only uploads the dist/ folder so steps are much quicker, and I am using npm instead of pm2 for the Startup Command. I have tried with pm2 serve, but it just says 'Waiting for response to warmup request for container...' for awhile before hanging up. My /wwwroot/ in KUDU is also empty, which suggests it is failing to build anything.

Comment: Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66871045/pm2-not-found-on-azure-app-service-with-node-14-runtime -- I changed the startup command to 'npx serve -s' and it looks like it works, I really don't know why though compared to 'npm run serve' or 'pm2 serve'

Answer (score 0):

I saw you are running your stages with different agents, so I suppose that your issue could be resulted from that the configuration in the `build stage agent` could not be inherited into the `deploy stage agent`.

So you could test to add the `npm task` to install the `vue-cli-service` module in your deploy agent again.

==========================================================

**Updated on 12/22**

I suppose that in deploy stage, you could add the npm and node installation with below.

```
      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '16.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
           npm install -g @vue/cli@latest
           npm i -g @vue/cli-service-global
           echo '<template><h1>Hello!</h1></template>' > App.vue
           vue serve
```

Comment: How would I implement this in .yml?

Comment: @TabulaRasa hi I have updated my answer you could check it for test